# UISplitViewController Master / Details are showing in the same pane

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to set up a split view controller on my app. It is handled in the storyboard, and the problem is the master and detail show in the same pane, and overlap each other. The detail never shows in the detail side, that the background you see on the master never goes away.Please see image below.
[image: Problem Image]

I have the Segues set up in the storyboard, the UISplitView is inside a UITabBarController.
[image]

Here are the connections:

**1: Relationship Segue - Master**

**2: Relationship Segue - Detail**

**3: Show Segue**

**4: Navigation Controller - Root View Controller.**